# ASP.NET Core 3.1 on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: asp.net-core, windows-server-2008-r2, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a WebAPI developped using **ASP.NET Core 3.1** that I need to deploy to IIS running on **Windows Server 2008 R2**. However the official documentation from Microsoft says that ASP.NET Core 3.1 is only supported on Windows Server 2012 and upward. The highest version supported on Windows Server 2008 R2 is ASP.NET Core 2.1.

Is there anyway I could still deploy this app to Windows Server 2008 R2?

*Thanks in advance.*

Comment: Try to install hosting bundle, and see what happens: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1

Comment: That bundle is not supporting WinServ 2008 R2

Comment: @ayou392 Any update to this problem?